# Adobe Illustrator 19 SVG Viewbox?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

We produce icons in Illustrator as SVGs and then produce font based icons with fontcustom. Out of no where, they were coming in too low. I found in the svg this odd viewBox with a negative 49 on it. How is this controlled in Illustrator? I don't want any viewbox, I just want a perfectly centered icon. I also see that it thinks that it is grouped. My only fix is to ungroup, and then set the X and Y to zero, and it works. It does put in a transform compensating to -49 on the layer. Something is causing this odd offset.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-49 141 512 512"
 style="enable-background:new -49 141 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Answer (score 2):

Viewbox in illustrator is based on the art board I believe and it's a pain to get it to match the artwork exactly. The easy way to zero it all out is to just highlight the object in illustrator select copy.. then go to your code editor, make a new document and paste it. It will copy the svg code with a the view box set correctly(starting at 0,0). Then just save the file as an svg and you're done.